# How to continuosly run MPI programs?

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm writing a C++ program using MPI to simulate traffic lights. Basically, I need that every two seconds, process 0 should send a message to all other processes (traffic lights) that they need to change colors. My current approach is something like (I don't have the actual code) :

```
if ( process_rank == 0)
{
   while(true)
   {
      Sleep(2000); //we sleep for 2 seconds

      for(i=1; i<=n;i++)
      {
         MPI_Send( message to change color to process i);
      }
   }
}
else
{
    MPI_Recv(message to change color);
}
```

The code is ok, no compilation errors, but the problem seems to be in my logic. For some reason I cannot understand, the program doen't do what expected. Is there a good way to continuosly run a MPI program and to send a message every X seconds? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your higher processes exit after the receive. If they shouldn't, the receives must be also in a loop.

Also the other logic of the program must fit there. You will probably se some functions to do the other useful stuff. Even the complete code for the master and for others may be in distinct functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <unistd.h>


int main(argc,argv)
  int argc;
  char *argv[];{
  int color, rank, numtasks;
  MPI_Status status;

  MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);

  if ( rank == 0)
  {
     color = 0;
     while(1)
     {
        sleep(2); //we sleep for 2 seconds

        for(int i=1; i<numtasks;i++)
        {
           color = (color + 1) % 3;
           MPI_Send((void*)&color, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
     }
  }
  else
  {
   while(1)
     {
      MPI_Recv((void*)&color, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
      printf("rank %i color is %i\n",rank, color);
     }
  }

  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: I see. That makes sense. By chance, do you have a working sample? It would be of really help to me.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try the code later, I'll return with a feedback.

Comment: I tried your solution, but for some reason I cannot understand, the output appears very seldom. I mean, should it pe printing stuff every 2 seconds?

Comment: Yes, and it works on my system (OpenMPI Linux). How and where are you running it? Did you copy my code exactly? There were couple of mistakes in your code.

Comment: Also, if you use Windows, set the number in `sleep()` call back to 2000 and include the appropriate header. I do not use Windows (or at least not with MPI).

Comment: Yes, it works. I had to call `fflush(stdout)` after each `printf`. Otherwise, it would not print it.